# Drop-off specific custom agents using drop-off block in anylogic

Tags: agent, anylogic

I would like to know how to calculate how many custom agents are within a container in anylogic so that i can use the value in a drop off block accordingly.

I have 4 custom agents, a, b, c, and d and 4 train stations 1, 2, 3 and 4. Each of these types of agent need to be dropped off according to a ratio i.e 40% of a needs to be dropped off at 3.

I understand how to use the drop off block, i just cannot calculate how many of each agent are within the container.

Answer (score 0):

to know how many agents are in the container:

```
container.contents().size()
```

to know how many agents of the class A are in the container:

```
count(container.contents(),agent->agent instanceof A)
```

To dropoff a certain percentage of the agents is answered in the following stackoverflow questions:
[Setting drop-off block in anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091486/setting-drop-off-block-in-anylogic/50092206#50092206)

To dropoff a certain percentage of a particular agent type is answered here:
[Anylogic: Dropoff given quantity using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162331/anylogic-dropoff-given-quantity-using-parameters/50167552#50167552)