# how to custom drop-off block according to agent type

Tags: anylogic

Using  previous pick-up blocks, i have an container agent with two different agent types inside (Myagent and Myagent1). I want to insert two different drop-off blocks,the first for Myagent and the second for Myagent1. the problem is which element type i should choose for the drop-off block. For example, if i chose Myagent, it would give me error because of Myagent1:
[image: error1]
If i chose Agent then:
[image: erro2]

Both the agent have a parameter named cc.
(I read other answers on the forum like [Drop-off specific custom agents using drop-off block in anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249659/drop-off-specific-custom-agents-using-drop-off-block-in-anylogic), but i still have this error).
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option here is to create a parent agent type that has 'cc' property and have the two types of agents inherit from it as described [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/inheritance.html#agent-inheritance). Also as a side note, you should probably take care to name the agents and properties with something meaningful as it will help to understand the model and explain it should you need to ask for help in the future.